# Joomla Pagination in custom component

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm working from one of the docs on the Joomla site.  I'm stuck on the part that tell you to revise the `getData()` function.

**"Revise the getData() function, adding the $limitstart and $limit values to the _getList() query. This causes only the needed rows to be returned, rather than all rows."**

```
function getData() 
{
    // if data hasn't already been obtained, load it
    if (empty($this->_data)) {
        $query = $this->_buildQuery();
        $this->_data = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit'));    
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

I have a function that already builds the mySQL query.  Is this the function it's wanting to change?  Does this code replace the the lines currently in my `getData()` function:

```
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $table = $db->loadRowList();
    return $table;
```

Do I just need to add this line to the function that builds the mySQL query or do I need to repalce something?

**EDIT:** The Joomla doc I am working off of can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JPagination_in_your_component).

Comment: I have similar problem, did you solved it?

Comment: I didn't solve it the way actualized in the Joomla doc I was working with.  I ended up creating an AJAX call to load my pagination for usability.

If you need help doing this, hit me up, I'd be glad to share my ideas with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This return all rows:

> $table = $db->loadRowList();

This will return only needed data, limited by the paginator:

```
if (empty($this->_data)) {
        $query = $this->_buildQuery();
        $this->_data = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit'));    
    }
    return $this->_data;
```

So you should replace `function getData()` in your model.